# Multiple Header Styles In Timber/Twig

Tags: php, wordpress, twig

I'm coding up a theme using Timber for Wordpress, which uses the twig templating engine.

I currently have different data needed for header sections on three pages.

1. Home Page > BG Slider & Title
2. Blog Page > BG & Pinned Post
3. Other Pages > Regular BG Image

The navigation is also supposed to be the same over each of these page headers.

I'm unsure of the best way to use twig to solve this problem.

In my base.twig I currently have:

```
{% block header %}
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h1 class="hdr-logo" role="banner">
                    <a class="hdr-logo-link" href="/" rel="home">{{site.name}}</a>
                </h1>
                <nav id="nav-main" class="nav-main" role="navigation">
                    <ul class="nav">
                    {% for item in menu.get_items %}
                        <li class="nav-item {{item.classes | join(' ')}}">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{item.get_link}}">{{item.title}}</a>
                            {% if item.get_children %}
                                <ul class="nav nav-drop">
                                {% for child in item.get_children %}
                                    <li class="nav-drop-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{child.get_link}}">{{child.title}}</a>
                                    </li>
                                {% endfor %}
                                </ul>
                            {% endif %}
                        </li>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </nav><!-- #nav -->
            </div>
        {% endblock %}
```

I could copy and paste this block onto each page, ie add it to

home.twig, blog.twig and other.twig

But i am repeating myself constantly, and it feels wrong. I need to feed through this on each page, without repeating my navigation each time i do it.

Does anyone have a suggestion as to how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

What you want are Twig macros and/or Includes

### [Includes](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html)

can be used to include another .twig file in your template.
You can add variables to an Include also, but by default code inside the include have acccess to global context. eg. all template variables.

```
{# template.html will have access to the variables from the current context and the additional ones provided #}
{% include 'template.html' with {'foo': 'bar'} %}

{% set vars = {'foo': 'bar'} %}
{% include 'template.html' with vars %}
```

### [Macros](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html)

Are isolated from the global context, and can only work with variables/parameters that you supply to it.

```
{# defineit #}
{% macro input(name, value, type, size) %}
    <input type="{{ type|default('text') }}" name="{{ name }}" value="{{ value|e }}" size="{{ size|default(20) }}" />
{% endmacro %}

{# then calling it #}
<p>{{ _self.input('username') }}</p>
```

With both Includes and Macros you can easily do infinitely nested trees, when you include itself in the loop.

Example of nested tree with include:

```
  {# content of tree.twig file for include#}
  {% for item in menu.get_items %}
        <li class="nav-item {{item.classes | join(' ')}}">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{{item.get_link}}">{{item.title}}</a>
            {% if item.get_children %}
                <ul class="nav nav-drop">
                {# recursion #}
                {% include 'tree.twig' with { menu : item.get_children } %}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
```